# Why don't I have to build setters & getters to use these variables?

Tags: objective-c, variables, methods, setter, getter

When I'm writing code inside the 'Cocoa Application' I am able to get away with not using the @property "bla bla bla"
and
@synthesize ". . . "

and still do what I want with my variables that i've declared. For example..

```
IBOutlet NSTextField *textField;
IBOutlet NSTextView *viewField;
```

and then simply build method's below these variables.

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
-(int)adding;
```

I am then able to go into the     .m  files and I could do things like

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
int myVariable = [self adding];

[viewField insertText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@".... %i", myVariable]];
```

}

```
-(int)adding {
    int myAge = [textField intValue];
    int myVariable = 100 - myAge;

    return myVariable;
}
```

I don't get why I can do all this without having made any setters & getters beforehand.

Can anyone explain. Thanks.

Oh and one more thing..

If a variable is only valid within the method in which it is declared, why am I able to do otherwise ..

for example

```
-(int)myMethod {
int variableA = 50;
```

}

```
-(int)myotherMethod  {
  int variableA + 100;
```

}

and it will give me the answer 150..

how does the 'myotherMethod' know that variableA is equal to 50. I thought they could't access each others variables..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The synthesized methods (getters and setters) are needed to access the instance variables from outside the class.  Code inside the class (in the instance methods) have direct access to the instance variables.  They're in scope for any code in the class implementation.  The scope is the entire class, not just a single method in the class.

joe

Comment: Aha! Haha, thank's Joe. I know it seems trivial but I got confused for a second. Thank's a lot. 

Can you clear up the last part for me too if you don't mind. 
It's just got me a bit confused.

TIA

Comment: That last one has me confused too.  I can't even guess without seeing all the code involved.  If it really is a local variable, you shouldn't be seeing that.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks again for all your help. I was wrong with the last part, it's not possible. I figured what I did wrong :)

Comment: If that answered your question, please go ahead and accept the answer.